# PGP, S/MIME and Thunderbird

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, pgp

I am using PGP encryption for my emails, my friend uses S/MIME. We both use thunderbird to write emails. When he writes me a signed email, I can verify the signature and, similarly, he can verify mine. However, we cannot send each other encrypted emails. The [thuderbird help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-help-cannot-encrypt) says

> You must have keys or certificates of the same technology for all
> recipients including yourself, because OpenPGP and S/MIME are separate
> encryption technologies and cannot be mixed in a single email. Ensure
> you have selected the correct technology when composing an encrypted
> email.

But why is this necessary? If my friend's thunderbird can verify my PGP signatures, it should be able to encrypt a message to me with my PGP public key, no matter that his key is S/MIME, or whether or not he even has any type of key himself.
Likewise, I should be able to encrypt messages to him, seeing that I can verify his signature. Am I overlooking anything? Maybe I didn't get 100% how exactly S/MIME differs from the PGP public/private key approach...

Comment: I don't see a question that can be clearly answered here.  Verification doesn't necessarily mean they can use and encrypt.  In PGP encryption of emails it is also intended to encrypt to *the sender's key* as well.  The system doesn't let you bypass that in Thunderbird inbuilt encryption with OpenPGP.  Which is probably why the other party can't encrypt *to* you.  To bypass that, they'd have to manually encrypt on the command line or similarly to you and then paste the encrypted in-line to the email content before sending.  S/MIME behaves similarly.

Comment: "In PGP encryption of emails it is also intended to encrypt to the sender's key as well" - oh, interesting, thanks. Do you happen to have a reference for that?

Comment: years of experience working in PGP signed mail and Thunderbird.  This isn't explictly documented, but as Kai stated in an email, Thunderbird won't let you save the message in an unencrypted state.  Which means that the original sender can't read if they don't have PGP keys of their own capable of decrypting the data.  Hence why they 'can't use PGP to encrypt' messaging because of TBird's implementations.  This also applies to S/MIME implementations as well

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I kinda confirmed that with the guys on bugzilla. Seems a shame though, in particular since the old Enigmail addon could "permanently decrypt" sent and received messages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending an encrypted email, Thunderbird wants to be able to store an encrypted copy of the message for yourself, saving it inside your Sent folder.
Because only one combined message is created for all participants of the email conversation (sender and all recipients), Thunderbird must have encryption keys of the same technology for everyone.
Requiring that everyone is ready to use the same encryption technology avoids the need to explain limitations and avoids unexpected consequences (such as missing emails in your Sent folder).

Comment: Hmm, I see. I guess I had kinda expected to have the option to store emails unencryptedly even though they were sent encryptedly.

Comment: I confirmed this also with Magnus Melin on the bugzilla. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> But why is this necessary? If my friend's thunderbird can verify my PGP signatures, it should be able to encrypt a message to me with my PGP public key, no matter that his key is S/MIME

That is true – as long as his key is not involved at all, it should be completely possible. But if he also wants to use his key to *sign* the encrypted message, that will conflict – the two systems both have their own data formats in which to package the signed/encrypted message, and you have to choose one format or the other, generally.

(Well, in theory Thunderbird could put a PGP message *inside* an S/MIME message, but the software does not support that at the moment.)

> Maybe I didn't get 100% how exactly S/MIME differs from the PGP public/private key approach.

In general, even though the two systems share the same basic algorithms of private/public keys, that is a relatively small part of what comprises them; it's like saying "trains and airplanes both have engines".

For example, it's technically true that both systems use RSA and EC, but in reality you never deal with plain RSA or EC public keys directly – you always deal with certificates, which are a bunch of metadata wrapped around the key, and the focus is primarily on the certificate rather than the actual key underneath. (Just to start with, your PGP certificate always has *two* keypairs inside – possibly more – while an S/MIME certificate has exactly one. The metadata formats also differ; the semantics attached to metadata fields are not the same; the file formats used to store the certificate are different.) So although it's technically simple to port an actual RSA key from one system to another, there is usually little to zero *meaning* in doing so, as the metadata won't carry over and that's the important part.

Another difference is the data formats. Both S/MIME and PGP have their own ways of packaging the signed/encrypted messages (or the keys/certs themselves) into a series of bytes, which are completely incompatible. If you have an S/MIME signed message, PGP software can't even begin to process it – keys don't even enter into the question, it doesn't even recognize what fields go where. (Much like you can store the same data as XML or as JSON, but software that expects XML won't be able to read JSON even if it's "the same data".)

Now, it would be technically possible to e.g. encrypt a message using PGP, store it in the PGP format, and then sign that using S/MIME, so that you have PGP-inside-CMS; both formats have the capability to do that. (Or the other way around, if you prefer.) But this brings to the last problem: they're handled by entirely different pieces of code inside Thunderbird which don't interact, so even if the CMS message indicates "I have a PGP message inside", Thunderbird's S/MIME code won't know what to do with that. It *could* be made to work, but at the moment I believe it does not work.

(Keep in mind Thunderbird had S/MIME capabilities for literally *multiple decades* before it gained PGP support – even before it was called "Thunderbird", or even "Mozilla"; it actually dates back to Netscape Communicator. In contrast, the PGP capabilities were added practically last year or thereabouts, before that they only came as a JS/XUL extension called Enigmail.)

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough information! What I take from the first part is that, if my friend does NOT want to sign their email but just encrypt and send it to me, then this should be possible. Since Thunderbird does not allow this at the moment (hence this post), it's well justified to make a feature request to them, right?